# Django Form Display Meta

Tags: python

I am still on Django tutorial and currently here:

```
def display_meta(request):
    values = request.META.items()
    values.sort()
    html = []
    for k, v in values:
        html.append('<tr><td>%s</td><td>%s</td></tr>' % (k, v))
    return HttpResponse('<table>%s</table>' % '\n'.join(html))
```

I understand what it is meant to do:

Display the Meta Data on a Http request in a html document.

What I dont understand is in

```
for k, v in values:
```

what k, v are standing for.

Any suggestions?

Thanks a lot

L.

Comment: They're variables.  That doesn't seem to be what you're really asking.  Are you asking how Python iterates through a list of 2-tuples?  Are you asking why the "key" is called "k" and the "value" is called "v"?  Can you clarify the question, please.

Comment: This has nothing to do with Django, and even less to do with forms. Tags changed to 'python'.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Is the method of iterating a Python dictionary `{'key':value, ...}`

`k` is the key and `v` is its value.